# Return match of any regex in an array given a string

Tags: php, regex

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php), `preg_grep` searches for a regular expression in an array.

Is there any function that will take an array of regular expressions and compare them to a string?

For example:

```
$arr = array("^foo-", "-bar$");

magic_function($arr,"Just a string"); // returns false
magic_function($arr,"foo-"); // returns true
```

Comment: I guess it would be possible to write your own function that goes through the array and matches each regex against the string, then returns true if at least one of them matches.

Comment: You're gonna have to make it yourself, it doesn't exist.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was surprised that preg_grep existed, and was wondering if there was a counterpart of some kind that I was just overlooking. @icedwater

Comment: @MisterMelancholy it is a fair question. But more often than not, if you can describe it within a few lines, it is easier to try writing your own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this, but you can easily build your own:

```
function magic_function($arr,$str) {
    foreach($arr as $regex) {
        if( preg_match($regex,$str)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the function. Just out of curiosity, would it be faster to use a `foreach` like this, or [array_map](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?

Comment: You can't break out of an `array_map`. This will only iterate as much as needed to find the match.

Comment: I see. That's good to know. Thanks for all of your help. I'll accept your answer once the waiting period is over.